# How to get TOKEN or API_KEY for FireBase?

Tags: firebase, api

I tried this method, recommended by google api
but i can't find.

```
  'https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: this method get all projects on my account
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/list?apix=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_here_your_project_name/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk - here generic key, download and get token over python for example

Don't forget get token over variable

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("/your__downloaded_json_file")
```